# import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.geocoding.PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder class not found

Tags: android, iso, libphonenumber

Probably missing something dumb, I'm guessing I need to add some code. But I added the following [jar file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/libphonenumber/7.0/libphonenumber-7.0.jar) to my project. The user enters a phone number and I'm able to retrieve the country phone code, but I want to retrieve the country name as well as the 2 letter ISO country code.

`PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder` should do that with it's `getCountryNameForNumber(PhoneNumber number, Locale language)` method should do that. But I can't figure out how to import that class properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include another jar from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/libphonenumber/geocoder/2.17/). PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder is not in `libphonenumber-7.0.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in gradle file:

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/geocoder
    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:geocoder:#'
```